# How to compare each element of an array using regex?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am using the Lingua::EN::Tagger Perl module in order to tag parts of speech from a user's input. That portion of my code works perfect. However, the problem is that I only want to keep the input that has the noun tags which are "NN, NNS, NNP, NNPS", and store these words in a separate array @nounArray. The user will be inputting a question such as "what is your name?" Each element of the question will be tagged: `What/WP is/is your/PN name/NN`

```
my @UserInput = $readable_text;
my @nounArray;
foreach my $UserInput (@UserInput){

    if ($UserInput =~ m/NN|NNS$|NNP$|NNPS$/){

              $UserInput = @nounArray;
    }
print @nounArray;
}
```

However, nothing occurs when I run the code. The goal is to have the nouns of the user's input be placed in a separate array after separating them from the original array. I do not want to print the array, but i do this in order to see if the code was working.

Comment: Why you added `$` in your regex?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, the reason i added the $ at the end is because the tags occur at the end of the words.

Comment: An example of the input would be "Can you turn off the lights?" It will be some form of a question. @mpapec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to iterate over the words in `$readable_text` you can split them first into array,

```
my $readable_text = "What/WP is/is your/PN name/NN";
my @UserInput = split ' ', $readable_text;
my @nounArray;
foreach my $UserInput (@UserInput) {

  if ($UserInput =~ m/NN|NNS$|NNP$|NNPS$/) {
    # print "$UserInput\n";
    push @nounArray, $UserInput;
  }
}

print @nounArray;
```

Comment: I don't just want to print the user input, I need to store the words with the noun tags in a separate array.

Comment: I tried the code with the update, it still is not giving me anything.There may be a problem with the regex, however I am not sure because i am getting no error.

Comment: @brilliantB check again. btw, which words do you want to catch in `What/WP is/is your/PN name/NN`?

Comment: the nouns.. for example name has the tag /NN therefore this would be considered a noun because they have the tags /NN /NNS /NNP /NNPS each stands for noun, nouns, proper noun, and proper nouns respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`$` matches at the end of the string. I suppose your strings have at least a `\n` at the end, which would prevent them from matching.

But as you point out in your comment, it looks like you're trying to match word boundaries here, so just replace all `$` in your expression with `\b`.

Comment: Yes I tried this and with a manipulation of my code it helped to only get the words that had /NN taggers. I removed all other taggers but kept only that one in my regex.

Answer (score 0):

First, split your words by whitespace:

```
my @UserInput = split /\s+/, $UserInput;
```

Then `grep` for the nouns:

```
my @nouns = grep { m%/N% } @UserInput;   # only noun tags include /N
```